# flex items don't stretch in cross axis when overflow is set to auto

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

As position:fixed has several disadvantages I'm trying to create a fixed footer by use of flexbox. I have a flex container with direction row and applied overflow-y:auto to it. Now when the content of a flex item exceeds the height of the visible area and the scrollbar appears the flex items do not stretch their height to the height of the container but stick to the height of the visible area. The result is that the text is not fully underlayed with the background color.
HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="middle">
    <nav>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
        aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </nav>
    <main>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod  et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet.

            Content shortened; more content to make the scrollbar appear

        </main>
</div>
<!-- Main Bereich Ende -->

<!--Footer Anfang -->
<footer>
    <div id="footerleft">
        <h2>Letzte Änderung
            <br>20.05.2018</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="footermiddle">
        <h3>Copyright © 2018 xxx - Alle Rechte vorbehalten</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="footerright">
        <a href="#jump-body">
            <img src="images/buttonup.png" title="Zum Seitenanfang" alt="Zum Seitenanfang"></img>
        </a>
    </div>
</footer>
<!--Footer Ende -->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    #middle {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: stretch;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    nav {
        flex: 1;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    main {
        flex: 4;
        background-color: maroon;
    }


    footer {
        width: 100%;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        display: flex;
    }

    #footerleft {
        flex: 2;
    }

    #footermiddle {
        flex: 6;
    }

    #footerright {
        flex: 2;
    }

    #footerright img {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0px auto auto;
    }
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: can make it a working snippet so we can better see the issue

Comment: Here it is: http://webentwicklung.ulrichbangert.de/thread-footer-verdeckt-fixed-footer.html Make the scrollbar appear and scroll down.

Comment: BTW: What does "question eligible for bounty in 2 days" mean? (English is not my mother tongue.)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `height: 100vh;` from `body` selector. By default height is auto so the body height will stretch according to its content. So instead of that use `min-height: 100vh;`.

Note: `img` tag shouldn't have a closing tag `</img>`

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    #middle {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: stretch;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    nav {
        flex: 1;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    main {
        flex: 4;
        background-color: maroon;
    }


    footer {
        width: 100%;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        display: flex;
    }

    #footerleft {
        flex: 2;
    }

    #footermiddle {
        flex: 6;
    }

    #footerright {
        flex: 2;
    }

    #footerright img {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0px auto auto;
    }
```

```html
<div id="middle">
    <nav>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
        aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </nav>
    <main>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod  et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod  et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod  et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod  et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet.

            Content shortened; more content to make the scrollbar appear

        </main>
</div>
<footer>
    <div id="footerleft">
        <h2>Letzte Änderung
            <br>20.05.2018</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="footermiddle">
        <h3>Copyright © 2018 xxx - Alle Rechte vorbehalten</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="footerright">
        <a href="#jump-body">
            <img src="images/buttonup.png" title="Zum Seitenanfang" alt="Zum Seitenanfang">
        </a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: No, I intend to have a fixed footer like position:fixed does. However as position:fixed has several disadvantages I'm trying to code a solution with flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I researched further and found this:
https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/141
A workaround for this issue is given. Can anyone of the flexbox experts explain? Is this really a bug in flexbox and is it cross browser?
Demo of the fix:
http://webentwicklung.ulrichbangert.de/thread-footer-verdeckt-fixed-footer-3.html

Comment: PS: This workaround works fine when there is a scrollbar. However when the viewport is wide the flex items nav and main don't expand to the height of div#middle. Any advice how to fix this too is appreciated.